# CornerRadius for WPF line

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there a possibility to change the CornerRadius for a Line in WPF as exists for border?

```
Line line = new Line
{
    Stroke = Brushes.Blue,
    StrokeThickness = 18,
    StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
    StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
    Height= 50,
    X1 = 50,
    X2 = 100,
    Y1 = 10,
    Y2 = 10
};
canvas.Children.Add(line);
```

[WPF line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGS4z.png)

Comment: No, `PenLineCap.Round` will always have a "CornerRadius" of `StrokeThickness / 2`. If you need a different Value, you can't use a `Line`.

Comment: What is the corner of a line? It has two end points, but obviously no corner.

Comment: @Clemens i think he means the rounding of the line cap

Comment: If it *is* the line cap, there are four flavors built in WPF : flat, square, round and triangle. you cannot really change their parameters afaik, but you could implement your own custom linecap : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2011/01/09/custom-line-caps-in-wpf/

Comment: ` Rectangle line = new Rectangle
            {
                Stroke =  Brushes.Blue,
                Width = 50,
                Height = 100,
                StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
                StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
                **RadiusX = 10**,
                **RadiusY = 10**
           
            }; ` You can change for rectangle, but RadiusX and RadiusY are not  available for Line.

Comment: @gnarpo RadiusX and RadiusY are for the corner radius of a Rectangle. A Line does not have a corner, so your question is pointless. If you would ask for Polyline, ok, but that also has no corner radius properties.